# On Dom Change through JS functions, update URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom, url-routing

I tried searching for any questions on StackOverflow that fit this and I believe that I am probably not using the proper language (phrasing the question properly) to pull up those questions. So I apologize if this is a repeat.

I currently am building a site with a high level of DOM changing through JS. Not exactly the best thing to use but works based on my technical skills. I had thought about using AngularJS to build out my project but there is a steep learning curve that is preventing me from making the switch. I did notice that AngularJS has a built in function that generates fake urls based on the data being pulled. Even though the user is not leaving the viewer the url updates to highlight the new information. I was wondering if their was a JS library that could replicate that function until I can pick up AngularJS and rewrite my code in it.

Thank you

Comment: jquery bbq, html5 state management , using pushState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a few that do what I need. I can't also figure out how to make a comment the accepted answer.

http://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/

https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/